# neural network xor gate classification

Tags: python, neural-network, backpropagation

I've written a simple neural network that can predict XOR gate function. I think I've used the math correctly, but the loss doesn't go down and remains near 0.6. Can anyone help me find the reason why?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

train_X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]).T
train_Y = np.array([[0,1,1,0]])
test_X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]).T
test_Y = np.array([[0,1,1,0]])

learning_rate = 0.1
S = 5

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_derivative(z):
    return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))

S0, S1, S2 = 2, 5, 1
m = 4

w1 = np.random.randn(S1, S0) * 0.01
b1 = np.zeros((S1, 1))
w2 = np.random.randn(S2, S1) * 0.01
b2 = np.zeros((S2, 1))

for i in range(1000000):
    Z1 = np.dot(w1, train_X) + b1
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
    Z2 = np.dot(w2, A1) + b2
    A2 = sigmoid(Z2)

    J = np.sum(-train_Y * np.log(A2) + (train_Y-1) * np.log(1-A2)) / m

    dZ2 = A2 - train_Y
    dW2 = np.dot(dZ2, A1.T) / m
    dB2 = np.sum(dZ2, axis = 1, keepdims = True) / m
    dZ1 = np.dot(w2.T, dZ2) * sigmoid_derivative(Z1)
    dW1 = np.dot(dZ1, train_X.T) / m
    dB1 = np.sum(dZ1, axis = 1, keepdims = True) / m

    w1 = w1 - dW1 * 0.03
    w2 = w2 - dW2 * 0.03
    b1 = b1 - dB1 * 0.03
    b2 = b2 - dB2 * 0.03

    print(J)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for posting! You question could use a bit of refining to help respondents know how to help. Can you point out why you think the math is right? It would also be helpful to see what `J` is outputting. What are the key components of back prop? Are they in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `dZ2` is not correct, as you do not multiply it with the derivative of sigmoid.

For the XOR problem, if you inspect the outputs the 1's are slightly higher than 0.5 and the 0's are slightly lower. I believe this is because the search has reached a plateau and therefore therefore progressing very slowly. I tried [RMSProp](http://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#rmsprop) which converged to almost 0 very fast. I also tried a pseudo second order algorithm, [RProp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rprop), which converged almost immediately (I used [iRProp-](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/articulo/2003-Neuro-Igel-IRprop+.pdf)). I am showing the plot for RMSPprop below

[image]

Also, the final output of the network is now

`[[1.67096234e-06 9.99999419e-01 9.99994158e-01 6.87836337e-06]]`

Rounding which gets

`array([[0., 1., 1., 0.]])`

But, I would highly recommend to perform [gradient checking](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Gradient_checking_and_advanced_optimization) to be sure that the analytical gradients match with the ones computed numerically. Also see [Andrew Ng's coursera lecture on gradient checking](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/Y3s6r/gradient-checking).

I am adding the modified code to with the RMSProp implementation.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]).T
train_Y = np.array([[0,1,1,0]])
test_X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]).T
test_Y = np.array([[0,1,1,0]])

learning_rate = 0.1
S = 5

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_derivative(z):
    return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))

S0, S1, S2 = 2, 5, 1
m = 4

w1 = np.random.randn(S1, S0) * 0.01
b1 = np.zeros((S1, 1))
w2 = np.random.randn(S2, S1) * 0.01
b2 = np.zeros((S2, 1))

# RMSProp variables
dWsqsum1 = np.zeros_like (w1)
dWsqsum2 = np.zeros_like (w2)
dBsqsum1 = np.zeros_like (b1)
dBsqsum2 = np.zeros_like (b2)
alpha = 0.9
lr = 0.01

err_vec = list ();

for i in range(20000):
    Z1 = np.dot(w1, train_X) + b1
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
    Z2 = np.dot(w2, A1) + b2
    A2 = sigmoid(Z2)

    J = np.sum(-train_Y * np.log(A2) + (train_Y-1) * np.log(1-A2)) / m

    dZ2 = (A2 - train_Y) * sigmoid_derivative (Z2);
    dW2 = np.dot(dZ2, A1.T) / m
    dB2 = np.sum(dZ2, axis = 1, keepdims = True) / m
    dZ1 = np.dot(w2.T, dZ2) * sigmoid_derivative(Z1)
    dW1 = np.dot(dZ1, train_X.T) / m
    dB1 = np.sum(dZ1, axis = 1, keepdims = True) / m

    # RMSProp update
    dWsqsum1 = alpha * dWsqsum1 + (1 - learning_rate) * np.square (dW1);
    dWsqsum2 = alpha * dWsqsum2 + (1 - learning_rate) * np.square (dW2);
    dBsqsum1 = alpha * dBsqsum1 + (1 - learning_rate) * np.square (dB1);
    dBsqsum2 = alpha * dBsqsum2 + (1 - learning_rate) * np.square (dB2);


    w1 = w1 - (lr * dW1 / (np.sqrt (dWsqsum1) + 10e-10));
    w2 = w2 - (lr * dW2 / (np.sqrt (dWsqsum2) + 10e-10));
    b1 = b1 - (lr * dB1 / (np.sqrt (dBsqsum1) + 10e-10));
    b2 = b2 - (lr * dB2 / (np.sqrt (dBsqsum2) + 10e-10));

    print(J)
    err_vec.append (J);


Z1 = np.dot(w1, train_X) + b1
A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
Z2 = np.dot(w2, A1) + b2
A2 = sigmoid(Z2)

print ("\n", A2);

plt.plot (np.array (err_vec));
plt.show ();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Actually, my problem was initializing the weights too small.

Comment: Also, I think my implementation for dZ2 is correct because dZ2 is the derivative of the last layer, so you don't have to multiply the sigmoid_derivative.

Comment: That's true that you need to make a proper initialisation of weights.
Say, you are learning in one single perceptron with sigmoid output. If you find the derivative of the mean squared cost function, you will end up finding the derivative of sigmoid (or any other thresholding function). Therefore the threshold derivative is required. Also, as I mentioned, make sure that you confirm your gradient computations using gradient checking.